# What type of butterfly or moth is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

Can anyone please determine if this is a moth or butterfly and what its name? We found it near a waterfall in the Philippines. There's actually a bunch of them and it seems that it's their natural habitat which is close to the waterfall and a stream along.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a butterfly known as a "Mapwing". It is in the family Nymphalidae. I'm pretty sure it is *Cyrestis maenalis*. https://wikivividly.com/wiki/Cyrestis_maenalis

Comment: I see. Thanks you so much for the info.